# activate automatic code analyses only on "save" in pycharm

Tags: python, code-analysis, pycharm

Python code gets automatically checked in Pycharm (3.4.1), which actually is a good feature. However, is there any way to disable the automatic code anaylsis and only do it on e.g. save.

The reason why I'm asking is, because the colors of the source code are constantly changing during typing and indicating an error even though I haven't fully finished the command in one line. IMO it is also distracting if the color of the class name is constantly changing during writing the docstring.

Does anybody have a solution/workaround for that? I currently changed e.g. the class name to the default color in order to avoid this.